# Cannot proceed alfresco installation because of encoding mismatch

Tags: alfresco

I am new to Alfresco and I am trying to install alfresco in my debian server(via ssh access) following the installation guide. However, the installation stops and shows me this error :

```
Error: There has been an error.
initdb.bin: encoding mismatch
The encoding you selected (UTF8) and the encoding that the selected 
locale uses (LATIN1) do not match. This would lead to misbehavior in 
various character string processing functions. Rerun initdb.bin and either 
do not specify an encoding explicitly, or choose a matching combination.
```

I tried updating the locales of the server but still the issue exists. How do I fix this?

Comment: What locale did you set when you ran the postgresql initdb? What locale do you have set now?

Comment: I did not run any postgresql initdb. What I did was to run the installer and it did not tell me any question about postgresql except the ports. Do I have to install postgresql prior to Alfresco installation? The locale set on my debian server is en_US .

Comment: Which version of the installer are you running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have successfully installed it by doing the following steps:

1. Commented out the Send_ENV in /etc/ssh/ssh_config variable in the local machine and Accept_ENV in /etc/ssh/sshd_config variable in the server.
2. Edited /etc/locale.gen to uncomment en_US.UTF-8.
3. Ran locale-gen
4. Edited /etc/locale.conf and added LANG=en_US.UTF-8.
5. Successfully installed alfresco.